# Hoberman Sphere : what parametrization?

Tags: geometry, surfaces, spherical-coordinates

I wondered if a *nice* spherical coordinate parametrization was known for something *a bit like* children expanding balls known as  [Hoberman spheres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoberman_sphere).

- a bit like means a map
  $$
  (t,\theta,\phi)->f(t,\theta,\phi)
  $$
  with $f$ continuous on $(0,1]\times[0,2\pi)\times[0,\pi]$ and $f(1,\theta,\phi)=1$ so that the domain
  $$
  \{(x,y,z)=(r\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi),r\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi),r\cos(\phi))~:~ 0\leq r\leq  f(0+,\theta,\phi)\}
  $$
  (where the notation "$0+$" means a positive arbitrarily small small value for t), looks like a spiky ball (more like a lot of spikes than a ball really).
- *nice* means something explicit enough that one can do computations with it : in fact, if it was a coordinate change, it would be fab'.

Comment: Sorry, trying to understand your first bulleted condition: what does 0+ mean? Do you mean that for each constant $t\in(0,1)$, the set of $(r,\theta,\phi)$ such that $r\leq f(t,\theta,\phi)$ "looks like" a spiky ball? (By your conditions for $t=1$ this set is precisely the unit ball.)

Comment: @GlenWhitney 0+ means in the limit as t tends to 0. It is a ball for t=1, it looks like a spiky ball for t=\epsilon << 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, you can get such a parametrization on $t\in[0,1]$ as follows. Choose your favorite spherical parametrization $g(\theta,\phi)$ of your favorite "spiky ball" contained in the unit ball. For example, using a regular octahedron as a crude spiky ball, you could choose the standard spherical parametrization thereof $$c(\theta,\phi)=\frac{1/2}{|\cos\theta\sin\phi| + |\sin\theta\sin\phi| + |\cos\phi|}$$ (where the 1/2 is chosen to make the longest diagonals of the octahedron have length 1 and fit the entire octahedron inside the unit ball). Then simply take the parametrization $f$ to be $$f(t,\theta,\phi) = t + (1-t)g(\theta,\phi).$$ I think that satisfies the desired constraints.

Now of course you may find a regular octahedron to be an insufficiently spiky ball. You might prefer something more like the [rhombic hexecontahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombic_hexecontahedron), or something even spikier. But the same process should provide what you want: just start with a polar parametrization of the desired "spiky ball" and linearly interpolate from there to the final unit ball.

Comment: Not very spiky in either cases.. did you look at what Hoberman spheres look like?

Comment: Well, I did note that you might want "something even spikier." In fact, a Hoberman sphere isn't really even a "spiky ball;" it consists of just the edges of an icosidedecahedron (folded up in some particular way). In other words, it doesn't even come close to covering any ball. That notwithstanding, it has 150 spikes: one for each of the 30 vertices of an icosidodecahedron and two for each of the 60 edges. So you might prefer an elevation of a polyhedron with 150 faces. A candidate, which should admit a decent polar parametrization, is a cube with each face subdivided five-by-five.

Comment: The folding is the crux of the matter: when folded, shows mostly radial spikes. So imagine an Hoberman sphere covered in spandex : onced expanded it is a sphere, once shrunk it is a bunch of pointy needles.

Comment: Well, is something like this pointy enough: http://levskaya.github.io/polyhedronisme/?recipe=keeeC# (obviously, the points can be made as "tall" as you like.)